# Insert div after every three posts in home.php

Tags: php, posts, loop, homepage

I want to insert a div with content into my posts page after every three posts are called from the loop.

I want to use this to display banner ads / newsletter signup call to actions.

This is from home.php

```
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ($wp_query->current_post === 3) {
    // your code
    }

        /*
         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );




    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) object has a property called `current_post` to indicates which post the loop is currently processing. So you can write a similar condition inside your loop:

```
global $wp_query;
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  if ($wp_query->current_post % 3 === 0) {
    // your code
  }
  // Your article
}
```

Comment: Adding your comment after Get_template_part or after While gives error undefined variable. Updated the question

Comment: Yes, you have to define access the global `$wp_query` object first. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works but only on the 4th post and does not repeat.

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to adjust the condition accordingly.